# What's the meaning of "messed up"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a comment made by an author who used to be a porn store clerk:

> I have to say that I thought it was pretty **messed up** when they stopped providing us with hand sanitizer. I'm not a prude by any means, but working around bodily fluids really isn't the safest thing in the world.

What does *messed up* mean here?

Comment: It's a very vague slang usage that strictly speaking should probably mean something like *inconsistent* or *confusing*, but often just means *extremely undesirable*.

Comment: In this context, _pretty messed up_ basically means _just plain wrong_, as in: "I thought it was just plain wrong when they stopped providing us with hand sanitizer." It could be used in a variety of contexts: _The way he slapped his girlfriend was pretty messed up,_ or, _When I found out how he had swindled more than 10 people in their 70s, I thought, "That's pretty messed up."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To over-verbalize it, if you will, "messed up" often means "indicative of misguided, mistaken, or just plain wrong thoughts about the matter at hand."

In the sample given, somebody at the company probably thought "if we cut out the hand sanitizer, we'll save thousands of dollars in a year" while totally ignoring the possibility of increased risk of infections or diseases; they mistakenly focused only on the cost instead of the safety.

When used of a person, directly, as in "(so-and-so) is pretty messed up", the same basic sense is there; the person has gotten themselves into a bad situation because of poor choices that they've made, which were avoidable with proper reasoning; and now, most likely, they can't see a way to get themselves out of it.